# Add Part of List to Wiki Page

Tags: list

Is it possible to add a part of a List (prefiltered) to be displayed on a wiki page?
I managed to add the whole list, but how can i add only parts of it?

Comment: You can add List web part on your wiki page. In list web part you can create your view and filter the list data.

Comment: [add list web part](http://www.isacantx.org/SharePointTraining/TrainingPages/ListView.html) this link may help you to add list web part on your page.....After Editing the web part, click on  "Edit the current view". Here you can filter your list as well as select the columns you want to show on page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add List web part on your wiki page. In list web part you can create your view and filter the list data.

[add list web part](http://www.isacantx.org/SharePointTraining/TrainingPages/ListView.html) this link may help you to add list web part on your page.....After Editing the web part, click on "Edit the current view". Here you can filter your list as well as select the columns you want to show on page.

Comment: have you tried this?